# VS 2010 doesn't detect any changes in code inside template

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Let's assume that I have written the next code in header file

```
template<typename MyType> 
inline void function()
{
    /*some code here*/;
}
```

When I press build solution in Visual Studio 2010 SP1Rel it builds code and I get the next

```
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

It seems like everything is fine, however If I add any code in the template (even if it is a code with error) VS doesn't detect changes and tells that build succeeded.
For example:

```
template<typename MyType> 
inline void function()
{
    this is a plane text so, compiler should give an error //line with error
    /*some code here*/;
}
```

result of build :

```
 ========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

If I add any code with errors outside the template, VS tells me that build FAILED and after that it actually finds all errors outside and inside template. Another way to force VS to detect any changes inside template is to rebuild the entire project, but in my case it takes too much time, so I would like to find some other way to force VS to detect changes in my code? Can anyone suggest why such situation happens and how I can overcome it?

Answer (score 5):

Code within template classes is not compiled if an appropriate instance of that template is not instantiated.

The standard mandates this and various metaprogramming techniques exploit it.